# Why are random characters being deleted from my SQL Server export?

Tags: sql-server, csv, export

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 to generate a '~'delimited dataset. My query output is being saved as a csv file with this custom delimiter set in SQL Server settings. The problem is, random characters are being deleted.

If I run 'results to text', the output is fine. If, however, I run 'results to file', random characters are being replaced with a single space. E.g., one of my entries in one of my fields reads 'North', and this is fine in 'results to text' output, but appears as ' orth' in 'results to file'. Similarly, some of my delimiters have gone missing: e.g. '1~1~1~1~1~1' is coming through as '1~1 1~1~1~1'.

I would happily copy and paste the 'results to text' output into notepad and save as a csv myself, but unfortunately it won't let me copy more than a few lines (my dataset is large).

Desperate for ideas if anyone has any. Many thanks.

UPDATE: I cannot get my code to work in the Export Wizard and I do not have access to SSIS as I am working within a very strict firewall. Does anyone have any ideas on why the error is occurring in the first place?

Comment: You shouldn't use SSMS to export data like that. Instead create an actual export (right click on database, tasks, export data)

Comment: @DavidG I'm not sure how to do that? I'm running a query, where am I right-clicking?

Comment: Did you read my comment?!

Comment: Yes I read your comment. I cannot see 'database' anywhere, hence my asking. If I could see where to right-click, I would not have asked "where am I right-clicking?"

Comment: Database = the database where your data is stored, the database against which you are running the query.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I'm now coming up against a different error using the Export wizard though. Unfortunately my code is long and complicated and the Export wizard cannot handle it.

Comment: I'd be VERY surprised that it doesn't work in there. But it may be easier to put the code in a stored procedure and call that instead.

Comment: The error reads 'This SQL statement is not a query'. However, it runs fine within SQL Server.

Comment: Stored procedure it is then

Comment: Sorry to be a pain - could you possibly help me with the syntax to do that? Let's say my filename is abc.sql

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, using SSMS to export data is fraught with issues, usually things like truncating long strings and adding random carriage returns. The best option is to use am SSIS task, especially if you want to run this job more than once. However, sometimes it's just as simple to use the SQL Export Data Wizard. Right click on the database where your data is, select *Tasks*, then *Export Data...* and follow through the wizard.

If for some reason the SQL you are using is not being accepted, then you could put it into a stored procedure. For example, lets say the query you had was something very simple:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM MyTable
```

You can put this into a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyData
AS    

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM MyTable
```

This means that the query is stored inside your database so you don't need an `.sql` file or to paste it into SSMS every time you need it.

And now the query you run is simply this:

```
EXEC GetMyData
```

Comment: @JimMichael Don't forget to upvote (when you have enough rep) and accept answers that give you a solution that worked for you.

Comment: Sure - have upvoted (already as you've noted I don't have enough rep so it's just stored as feedback)

Answer (score 0):

I never use those results other than quick checking.  As commented it is better to run the export wizard.  I suggest going one step further and using the SSIS designer to create that package instead.  It will be easier to maintain and build upon in the future.

Here is a good video tutorial on a site with other great SSIS stuff:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCdPzdD-boQ

Here is a good non video tutorial:
http://knowlton-group.com/using-ssis-to-export-data-to-flat-files/

One is for pipe delimited and the other for comma, but in both cases the delimiter can be changed to ~

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I do not have access to SSIS on the server I am using. Would be great to resolve the issue using internal SQL Server options.

Comment: You can run ssis packages from the VS shell on a workstation.  Just need to install the latest SSDT.  The export wizard you are looking into actually creates an SSIS package and does not use internal SQL Server options.  Those would be openrowset and bulk copy, which you can look into using, but in my opinion SSIS designer is much more easy to use.